# Parsing JSON data in RAILS 3.0.6 received from HTTP POST with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http-headers

I am receiving an HTTP POST from a 3rd party with content-type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in my RAILS 3.0.6 controller

I tried parsing the request both as -

job_status = params['job']['status']

as well as

recd_json = JSON.parse(params)
 job_status = recd_json['job']['status']

But in both cases the rails controller is throwing the error 'NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.'

I am not sure how else can JSON (encoded using this content type) can be parsed..Any help is appreciated :)

Heres the json being posted:
{
    "name": "JSON Parser",
    "url": "job/test/",
    "job": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "url": "job/356/"
    }
}

Heres the params as returned by the RAILS controller using the Rails.Logger:

{"{    \"name\": \"JSON Parser\",    \"url\": \"job/test/\",    \"job\": {        \"status\": \"SUCCESS\",        \"url\": \"job/356/\"    }}"=>nil, "action"=>"receive_jobs_updates", "controller"=>"jobs"}

The Error trace:

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:32:in `receive_jobs_updates'

The controller code:
def receive_job_updates

Rails.logger.info params

job_name = params['name']
  job_status = params['job']['status']

render :text=> "All ok"  , :status => :ok

end

Comment: Please paste the code of the controller action that's throwing the error, as well as the complete backtrace of the error.

Comment: Heres the params returned by the RAILS controller:{"{    \"name\": \"JSON Parser\",    \"url\": \"job/test/\",    \"job\": {        \"status\": \"SUCCESS\",        \"url\": \"job/356/\"    }}"=>nil, "action"=>"receive_job_updates", "controller"=>"jobs"}


NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
  app/controllers/job_controller.rb:32:in `receive_job_updates'

Comment: Sorry this is hardly readable..please refer to the edited question post

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Job` object: `job_status = Job.new(params[:job]).status`

Comment: Without knowing the model/controller setup I made a guess as to the object you're casting the params to.

Comment: job_status is part of the fields that go into a model Job. So instead of creating a new model I tried  job.job_status = params['job'].status..Again the same NoMethodError..